# Execute external command, exit script and interact with external command

Tags: python, exec, subprocess

Is there any alternative to Perl's `exec();` in Python?

I need Python to call external command, kill itself, and I can then interact with external command.

In Perl I can just call `exec("command argument");`

I was trying to achieve this with the `subprocess` module, but it seems I'm missing something.
If I call `subprocess.call`, I can interact with child process, but parent is still running.
If I run `subprocess.Popen`, the child is killed as soon as the parent exits.

- OS is UNIX.
- Python is 2.6.4 (can't install any module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The family of [`os.exec*`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-management) functions do this.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed this one. Funny that I was checking os module. Ok thanks a lot guys, quick and nice help.